# Odoo server restart eror

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, odoo

I have created a model now I am using this command to restart the module
but it is showing this error

using this command to restart module

```
odoo start --config=/etc/odoo/odoo.conf -i HelloModule
```

the error is

```
odoo: error: The config file '/etc/odoo/odoo.conf' selected with -c/--config doesn't exist or is not readable, use -s/--save if you want to generate it
```

the screenshot of the file which error shows that it is not available

[image: the screenshot of the file which error shows that it is not available]

Comment: `etc/odoo/odoo.conf` is probably a different file than `/etc/odoo/odoo.conf` depending on what your current directory is. What happens if you run `vi /etc/odoo/odoo.conf`? (note the leading `/`)

Comment: same file opens. It is just that I enter command insdie "/" directory.

Comment: Try `sudo chmod +r etc/odoo/odoo.conf`, and use your commande as super user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding readable permission to config file by chmod command

`sudo chmod +r etc/odoo/odoo.conf`

Check this [link](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/modify-file-permissions-with-chmod/) to know more about modifying file permissions.